# What is the meaning of "snuggled up warm" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "snuggled up warm" in the following sentence,

> We were all cosy, **snuggled up warm**

?

Does it mean "We were all cosy and we snuggled up and we were warm" ?
or
does it mean "We were all cosy and we snuggled up in order to be warm" ?

Can we use the adjective "warm" instead of a noun behind the preposition "up"?

Grammatically, I have thought nouns came after prepositions. But, I often have seen many sentences with adjectives after prepositions. Is there a rule to make a sentence like this?

Comment: I think 'warm' is a complement here.

Comment: If so, does it mean "We were all cosy and we snuggled up and we were warm" ? Can we place complements anywhere in the sentence even after prepositions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd understand this as "we were all cosy as a result of snuggling up warm".

My understanding is mostly pragmatic, based on my understanding of the situation. I know that snuggling results in being cosy, so regardless of any grammatical analysis, this must be the intended meaning.

I do agree that warm is a complement. It tells you what the person is.